# Angular Autocomplete - Filter by starting letters of the words in

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, autocomplete

Here I got a list of countries in an autocomplete dropdown and tried to filter those by starting letters of the country name.

Example: If we type "Aus", all the country name with "aus" are being filtered. (See screenshot). I want to filter only "Australia and Austria" or any other country names with starting letters "Aus".

How to do that?

[image]

```
<ng-autocomplete #countryList formControlName="locationCountry" [data]="countries"
   min-length="1" [searchKeyword]="countrykeyword"
   [initialValue]="countrykeyword"
   (selected)='selectEventCountry($event);onLocationSubmit();'
   (inputCleared)='onCountryCleared($event, false)'
   [itemTemplate]="countryListTemplate"
   [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate" placeHolder="Enter Country">
</ng-autocomplete>
```

Comment: you can use custom pipe , check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670236/10607908

Comment: It's impossible for me know "what" autocomplete you're using, check if there'r a way to reemplace the "search function" -if there're an `@Input` or similar-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Angular AutoComplete Inputs](https://github.com/gmerabishvili/angular-ng-autocomplete#inputs),

| Input | Description |
| --- | --- |
| customFilter | Custom filter function. You can use it to provide your own filtering function, as e.g. fuzzy-matching filtering, or to disable filtering at all (just pass (items) => items as a filter). Do not change the items argument given, return filtered list instead. |

You can define your custom filter logic and pass it to `[customFilter]` @Input property.

---

### SOLUTION

> .component.html

```
<ng-autocomplete #countryList formControlName="locationCountry" 
    [data]="countries" 
    min-length="1"
    [searchKeyword]="countrykeyword" 
    [initialValue]="countrykeyword"
    (selected)='selectEventCountry($event);onLocationSubmit();' 
    (inputCleared)='onCountryCleared($event, false)'
    [itemTemplate]="countryListTemplate" 
    [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate" 
    placeholder="Enter Country"
    [customFilter]="customFilter">
</ng-autocomplete>
```

> .component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  customFilter = function(countries: any[], query: string): any[] {
    return countries.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()));
  };
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete-uitt3y)

Comment: Hi,
How to I call API to get data in customFilter()?
I got an error: core.mjs:6495 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @NguyenPhong, perhaps try to create a new question and provide the minimal code, error and sample data for reproduction purposes. Look forwards to your question. Thanks.